# How do I automate a sequence of server updates?

Tags: sql-server, windows, remote-desktop

At my job, I occasionally have to perform the following tasks:

1. Use Remote Desktop Connection to log on to a server.
2. Copy a set of files from a specific folder on my computer to a specific folder on the server.
3. Execute an SQL query on the server in SQL Server Management Studio, copied from a text file on my computer.
4. Log out of the server.

And then repeat for a whole bunch of other servers. This adds up to more than an hour, and I'm trying to figure out a way to automate it. What's the best way to go about doing this? I don't think Windows is as feature-rich as Linux when it comes to the command line, and I'm inexperienced with network protocols as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this kind of behavior using batch files and scheduled tasks.

You can install the Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433

And find reference material for the utilities it offers here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162816.aspx

You will want to write a batch file that executes your actions in order. I recommend running a non-lethal SQL query against a test database while you develop your batch file, but it will be something like this:

```
::Copy the files
xcopy "\\server\c$\Source\*.*" "\\server\c$\Destination\"

::Set your MS SQL variables
set /p SName="Server Name"
set /p UName="User Name" 
set /p Pwd="Password"
set /p DbName="Database Name"

::Execute your SQL query
sqlcmd -S %SName% -U %UName% -P %Pwd% -d %DbName% -i "c:\sqlCommand.sql"
```

Then you'll want to set it up to run as a Windows scheduled task by a user account (or service account) that has access to both of these network locations.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Is there a reason to use xcopy over robocopy, or a batch file over a PowerShell script for that matter?

Comment: I think you could probably do similar behavior in PowerShell, but I don't have any expertise that I can offer about it.